# Как перемножить все цифры числа в Си?

Tags: c

У нас уже задано 3-значное число (ранее уже делалась операция нахождения суми первих двух цифр числа). Код операции:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main(){
int number = 576;
printf("number= %d\n",number);
int sum1 = 0;
int sum;
int res;

do { sum1 = sum1 + number%10; number = number/10;
} while(number>0);
sum = sum1 - (6);
printf("sum= %d\n",sum);

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Как перемножить все цифры в заданом числе и вивести результат? Пробовала std::string но не знаю как преплести заданое число **и всё это в Си**. Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: `ранее уже делалась операция нахождения суми` — покажите, данные задачи очень похожи. `Пробовала std::string` — это не Си.

Comment: Ээм, поменять плюс на умножение? Ну и заменить начальное значение.

Comment: P. S. А это вообще загадка `sum = sum1 - (6);`

Comment: Alexey Ten, уже пробовала, не работает

Answer (score 0):

Не вполне корректно, но мой GCC переварил - возможно, справится и ваш.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int number = 576;
    int answer = 1;

    printf("number= %d\n",number);

    for (;number > 1; number /= 10)
        answer *= (number % 10);

    printf("answer= %d\n", answer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а можно, что ваш код умножения как-то вставить в мой код сумы, чтобы получилось одно целое?

Comment: @Лена, я обновил ответ